# How to troubleshoot ajax calls not being executed simultaneously in PHP backend?

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous, soap

I am developing a web app that needs to call functions from a web service using SOAP.

I have coded a simple PHP backend to access the SOAP functions. The backend mainly consists of classes with static "helper" methods (I use __autoload() to load the classes only when needed).

At some point in the app, I need to call two SOAP functions at the same time. Since I want to speed up the process, I use two simultaneous ajax calls.

The thing is, those calls don't always run simultaneously. The requests are sent at the same time, but the second call lasts longer than the first one (they should have roughly the same run time). If the first call lasts 600 ms, the second one lasts 1400-1600 ms.

I have setup a simple test, where I call both functions first in parallel and then, when both requests are complete, in serial one after the other.

[image: Request test with second call lasting longer]

I have tried profiling the PHP side (both using microtime() and xdebug), but I've consistently found that the calls have the same execution time on PHP (about 500ms).

What is REALLY driving me insane, though, is the fact that the very same code seems to work and break in an apparently random fashion. Sometimes I reload the page and the calls are executed simultaneously. Then I reload again, and the second call takes longer, once more.

[image: Request test with expected results]

PHP Session lock should not be an issue, I open the session only when needed and close it with session_write_close() afterwards.

The SOAP server called by the php backend supports multiple connections, and besides my microtime() profiling has shown me that it takes about 400ms to complete a SOAP request, so I don't think the web service is to blame.

On the client side, the requests are sent at the same time. I tried adding a slight delay to the second call, to no avail.

But then again, this "random" behaviour is baffling me.
I have tested the app both on local (WAMP) and on two different servers (shared hosting). In all of the environments, PHP 5.5 was used.

What could be causing this discrepancy, and how could one try to isolate the problem, if the behaviour is not 100% consistent?

Comment: All AJAX requests are asynchronous and therefore can run and finish as they like. This is why you see something seemingly random. Even if the requests occur simultaneously there is no guarantee the information will ever return simultaneously. You may need to re-think your logic here.

Comment: As @JayBlanchard noted, AJAX is asynchronous. Further, TCPIP is asynchronous. If you send out request 1 followed by 2 followed by 3, you can get the responses back as 1,2,3, 2,1,3, 3,2,1, etc... Further, the web server is not required to handle requests in order. It likely does, but it is not required to do so. In the end, there is no reason to assume two requests sent at the same time will process at the same time.

Comment: There are some fluctuations in the timings, but they are, generally speaking, consistent.
What bothers me is that it's always two cases:
1) both requests are resolved in the same amount of time
2) request B ALWAYS takes more than double the time of request A (or request B itself, should it be called on its own). Despite this, the PHP processing always takes the same amount of time.
The randomness I refer to is the way it seems to switch between those two cases (and those two only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the mystery.

In my local environment, once I disabled xdebug, the ajax calls ran flawlessly in parallel.

In remote, I still had the same problem (and no xdebug at all).
So first of all, I've tried using one single AJAX call to a PHP script that used curl_multi_exec() to run the SOAP requests in parallel, basically a similar setup but mainly server-side.

I found that I had the same discrepancies in the timings using this technique as well, with a very similar pattern.

I've contacted the hosting provider explaining my problem, and they told me that it might be due to the shared environment having limited resources depending on the overall load.

So in the end while it's possible to achieve this behaviour, in my specific case I had to change my strategy and use two serial AJAX calls, updating the view after the first call to give the impression of a faster response while waiting for the second call to complete.